# jQuery Accordion Menu. Expand neighbor div as menu expands

Tags: php, jquery, html

For sake of simplicity, my site has two floated DIV blocks.  #Sidebar and #Content.  In my sidebar, I have a jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu, which expands. (Duh, it's an Accordion Menu)

Anyhow, when a user clicks on one of the submenu headers, it expands the menu and forces its containing DIV to expand as well.

I'm looking for a way, using jQuery, to expand #Content to the same size as #Sidebar, as #Sidebar is expanding.  Is this possible?

I have tried the normal way to make both DIV's the same size, but it does so when the page loads, not dynamically.

Thanks for any help!
Rick

Comment: Why would you want them to be the same size?  Isn't the content significantly larger than the sidebar?

Comment: Not same size, but rather same height.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the accordionchange event a function like so:

```
$("#Sidebar").bind('accordionchange', function () {
    $("#Content").height($("#Sidebar").height());
});
```

That should set the heights to be equal when the animation completes.

EDIT: You may also bind it in the accordion initializer by setting the `change:` field to your function to run when the accordion has changed

Comment: OK, it's late and I'm typing fast... My accordion menu is not jQuery, it's just JavaScript.  Is there a way to do it with a NON jQuery accordion?  Maybe fire it after #Sidebar is done expanding? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood you calling it a "jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu". Anyway, no matter. If it is your own accordion then put that same function as a callback when the bar is done expanding. I would imagine you could just store the function in a variable and call the variable as a function when your animation completes.

Comment: Thanks Los Frijoles, but you read correctly.  I just mistyped...  I appreicate your input and I'm going to give it a try.  Thanks again!